# convert third party text editor value to HTML in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, editor

I'm trying to convert text editor content to html, There are lots of solution over the internet to convert wysiwyg text to html but in my case the text is not coming from the wysiwyg, it's coming from the contentful(cms) by calling the API.

Text coming from the API (Text written in text editor)

```
__Das brauchst du dafür:__

- hellblaue Pappe (DIN A4 oder ein kleineres Format) oder fertig gefaltete Karte zum selbst gestalten
- weiße Fingermalfarbe für die Blüten
- schwarze oder grüne Farbe für den Blumenstil
- Stifte zum beschriften
```

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if contentful has a WYSIWYG functionality, but if so the API should return html. So maybe check if you can change the content field for it. If not, then you probably have to manually convert your text via PHP or JS, depending how you pull the data from API. You will need regex to define rules like `__ xx __` means bold text or `-` at beginning is a list item. Then convert the text into html using your custom converter

Comment: Have you tried anything so far that you can show us?

Comment: No, contentful is not supporting WYSIWYG, for instance I write the expression but there are lots of text fields I'm getting maybe there are more expression as well just like my above example we have "__" and "-".

I need to find the optimal solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found the solution we can use this library to parse down the text to HTML https://github.com/erusev/parsedown